# SSH config file is not being applied

Tags: ssh

I'm running Mac Os Lion and have the following ssh config file:

```
$ cat /Users/fernando/.ssh/config
Port 123
```

This should result in ssh connecting always on port 123, no?

Well, what happens is that it still tries to connect on 22:

```
$ ssh 192.168.0.11 -v
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/fernando/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.11 [192.168.0.11] port 22.
```

Any ideas of why this config is not applied? Is ssh config file cached?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if you add a `Host` directive to that config file?

```
Host *
  Port 123
```

Comment: Indeed, larsks. "Port 123" is not a valid .ssh/config. From ssh_config man page: "The configuration files contain sections separated by ``Host'' specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification."

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `~/.ssh/config` to this and see if it works:

```
Host 192.168.0.11
        Port 123
```